# Laravel - Get nested relation with "whereHas"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have three models `Period` , `Post`, `User`:

- `period` and `posts` have M:N relationship on `period_posts`
- `posts` and `user` have M:N relationship on `views`

**Period Model:**

```
class Period extends Model
{

    public $timestamps=false;

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

**Post Model:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function periods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Period::class);
    }


    public function views()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'views')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;



  public function views()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'views')
          ->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

**views Table:**

`id`
   `user_id`
   `post_id`

I need to get all `periods` with its `posts` where `auth user` have not seen (by views relationship)

I tried to do this but that did not work :

```
    $period = Period::whereHas('posts.views', function ($users) {
        $users->where('user_id', auth()->Id());
    })->get();
```

Comment: So you've to get all periods with its unseen posts for the authenticated user?

Comment: Does the views table contain only the seen posts?

Comment: views table contains `post_id` and `user_id` ...in another word `post` have m:n relation with `user` using `views` table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that your models are a little bit "messy" you can get what you want with Eloquent but you've to split the logic into a few parts.

Example:

```
// Get all user seen posts #1
$seenPosts = Auth::user()->views()->pluck('id');

// Get all user unseen posts with its period inside the collection #2
$posts = Post::whereNotIn('id',$seenPosts)->with('periods')->get();
```

Comment: i have three m:n relationship .. i have tow pivot table `views` and `posts_period` 
.. posts with period have M:N relation not one to many

Comment: Ok, you can get everything with the previous code. First, you've to get all user seen posts (#1). Then you can get all unseen posts with its periods(#2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use whereDoesntHave, I tested in my computer, and it runs well:

```
$post_ids = Post::whereDoesntHave('views', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id',Auth::id());
})->get()->pluck('id');
$periods = Period::whereHas('posts', function($q) use($post_ids){
    $q->whereIn('post_id',$post_ids);
})->get();
dd($periods->pluck('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have a model for views table, you could use View model to find all the unseen posts.

```
View::where('user_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->groupBy('post_id')->whereHas('posts')->pluck('post_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution does the same with only one query:

```
Period::query()
      ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('views', function ($query) {
          $query->where('users.id', '=', auth()->Id());
        }, '=', 0);
    });
```